# Anyone mind moving this question to stackoverflow, I flagged but no moderator takes it yet

Tags: support, status-completed

Can anyone migrate this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44636/make-virtualbox-kernel-modules-builtin-rather-than-modules-half-done) to stackoverflow.com ?

I already flagged it, but no one's doing it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's migrated now. For future reference, you can see the results of flags on your [flag summary page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/11318) -- there was a response to the flag you're talking about ages ago